# Why Are we getting "WD view: View name 'XXX' is already taken" when running Drush; and how can it be fixed?

Tags: drush

We are getting the following output whenever we run the drush script. This is problematic in logs when the drush cron is run. What is causing this and how do we fix it?

This started showing up recently after implementing a responsive design.

Here is an example of the output we get when running a drush command:

```
WD view: View name 'uft_admin_content' is already taken      [error]
WD view: View name 'uft_calendar' is already taken           [error]
WD view: View name 'contract_navigation' is already taken    [error]
WD view: View name 'faq' is already taken                    [error]
WD view: View name 'forms' is already taken                  [error]
WD view: View name 'reports' is already taken                [error]
WD view: View name 'news' is already taken                   [error]
WD view: View name 'upcoming_events' is already taken        [error]
WD view: View name 'chapter_news' is already taken           [error]
WD view: View name 'education_labor_news' is already taken   [error]
```

Comment: Is that for any command or just specific ones?

Comment: What version of Views and what version of Drupal are you using? Is it possible that this bug is related: https://www.drupal.org/node/455364